# Regular Expression for repeating number sequences

Tags: regex, numbers, expression, repeat

I'm after  a reg expression that allows a sequence of between 4 - 8 numbers but the first two and last two can not be the same.

For example

1245612 - contains a match
346731 - no match
789287 - no match
789278 - contains a match

Comment: `346731` how is this not a match? And how is this `1245612` a match? Your description is contradicting your example.

Comment: @nhahtdh `12xxx12` is a match, and `34yyy31` is not. Sounds clear.

Comment: You don't automatically need a regex for this. The number of the last 2 characters can be otained with a mod 100 function. The first 2 can be otained by an int division for example. It depends if you have a String or an Integer to work with.

Comment: @LaGrandMere: The description: "the first two and last two **can not** be the same. "

Comment: @nhahtdh : mmmmh ... I see ! Well, looks like I saw the regex should match when the sequence is not good, that's why it seemed clear to me ... Looks like there are 2 kinds of people, the ones who think the regex matches bad sequences, and the others who think that the regex matches the good sequences :)

Comment: I had tried (\d)\d{0,4}\1 but missed the extra \d.

Comment: I do need to use Javascript as its part of a CustomValidator for MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the first two and last two digits to be the same to match (your examples suggest this) than the regex `^(\d\d)\d{0,4}\1$` is the appropriate.

See http://regexr.com?33uuu for the regex on your examples.

Comment: Cheers for that i was nearly there but regex always get me

Comment: Although it works fine in a test - when i come to use it as data-val-regex-pattern="(\d\d)\d{0,4}\1" - it always gets flagged up as invalid

Any thoughts

Comment: @amun1000 Backslash `\ ` is in Javascript strings used to start an [escape sequence](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/escapesequence.shtml) and to get a `\ ` in your string you have to escape the `\ ` itself with `\\ `.

Comment: @stema OK this has got my head done in - here's what it looks like on the page 
<pre>    data-val-regex="Invalid" data-val-regex-pattern="^(\d\d)\d{0,4}\1$" id="PINNumber" <code>

But any entry into the input is flagged up as invalid - I try the same expression on a web based regex tester and its fine

Any suggestions?  Much appreciated

Comment: @amun1000, you should put the language you are using and a short working code snippet, or e.g. a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), that shows the problem, into your question. Then you will get the best answers. The more information,about the problem, you give us, the better we can help.

Comment: @stema looking at the way jquery executes this regexp it uses  `(new RegExp("^(\d\d)\d{0,4}\1$")).exec(1212);`  which always returns null

Comment: @stema Hi I've put together a jsfiddle example.  Notice that the Invalid PIN is displayed even after clearing the input and then enter a single value  http://jsfiddle.net/amun1000/rbAtp/16/

Comment: @amun1000, to me your example seems to be working. If you enter a Pin that is at least 5 chars long and starts and ends with the same two digits, then it is valid and of course it is invalid when you enter a single digit, that does not fit your pattern.

Comment: @stema, if you enter 123412. This is validated which is incorrect (repeating 12's). However if remove the trailing '2' (12341) it is invalid! - this for me should be valid. Only repeating number patterns are invalid eg 124512, 1212.  Its like its the opposite of what shouldbe happening.  Sorry for all this

Comment: @amun1000, you are validating with the pattern that matches the incorrect PINs, so of course it is the opposite that is happening. Have you read my answer? See the second solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rbAtp/18/)

Comment: @stema - thats looking fine thank you for time and support on this

Answer (score 1):

You have two possibilities:

1. Match when the two pairs are the same

   ```
   ^(\d{2})\d{0,4}\1$
   ```

   See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?33uu9)
2. Match when the two pairs are different

   ```
   ^(\d{2})\d{0,4}(?!\1)\d{2}$
   ```

   See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?33uuf)

The anchors `^` for the start of the string and `$` for the end of the string are important, otherwise you will get partial matches.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want what you described (for the first two and last two digits to **not** match), then you could do something like this:

```
(?!(\d\d)\d{0,4}\1)\d{4,8}
```

The first part of the expression asserts that it does *not* match an expression of the form [two digits][between 0 and 4 other digits][the same two digits again], and then aside from that it will match any sequence of digits from length 4 to 8.

Try out this regex in action (with Javascript-style regexes):

http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=(%3F!(%5Cd%5Cd)%5Cd%7B0%2C4%7D%5C1)%5Cd%7B4%2C8%7D&input=3366

Comment: Give it "1234512" and it will match on the "234512" part.

Comment: @stema, I fail to see the problem. He never specified that the sequence should be the whole string; but if that is the requirement, it is simple to prefix the regex with ^ and suffix it with $

Comment: Without anchors your regex matches on input strings that should fail.

Comment: @stema, You assumed that the requirement was to match the entire input string and not simply a sequence anywhere in the string. That was never specified.

Answer (score 0):

For this task reg expression not need or i not understand this task.
U need only to compare i[0] and i[1] with i[n] and i[n-1].